Compare historical volatility of swap rates with implied swaption volatility
Say I have 6 months daily 1Y swap rates historical and I can calculate the variance. Now I want to compare with the implied swaption volatility, say 3M1Y. If on the implied surface I read 10%, then in order to compare this with the historical variance I can manually calculate, do I need to do 10%*10%*1/2?
